# Не работает запрос в Golang и работает в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, golang

Один и тот же запрос не работает в Golang ( не может прочитать данные- возвращает 0 значение)
и работает в PostgreSQL

```
SELECT "Hash", "Name", "Type_id", "Image", "Active", "Set", "CreationTime" 
FROM "Product" WHERE "Hash"::text in 
(select u from unnest( string_to_array('1,2,3',',') ) u) ORDER BY "Hash" 
LIMIT 999999999 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: @Kromster наверное имелось ввиду postgreSql

Comment: да  это PosgreSQL

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы делаете запрос из Go.

Comment: @D-side код упомянут в запросе

Comment: @AndreKalinin это код **не** на Go.

Comment: заработало  "батю" заменили на текст